# MS Access - Join tables where value is similar if only a LEFT function is used?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can you join 2 tables if they look like this?

Table 1

```
Key_ID    Item
1234.P    User 123
4324.P    User 234
5432.P    User 345
```

Table 2

```
Key_ID    Item
1234.J    Computer ABC
4324.J    Computer DEF
5432.J    Computer GHI
```

If I can eliminate the last 2 characters of each Key_ID, the values would be identical. Does something along these lines work?

```
FROM [Table 1]
    INNER JOIN [Table 2]
    ON Left(([Table 1].Key_ID), Len([Table 1].Key_ID) - 2) =  
        Left(([Table 2].Key_ID), Len([Table 2].Key_ID) - 2)
```

The values to the left of the period in Key_ID may contain alpha characters, and may be more or less than 4 characters.

Comment: I don't know, have you tried doing it?

Comment: yes the `LEFT` function exists.  see the [MS ACCESS - LEFT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/left-function-HA001228873.aspx) documentation

Comment: My syntax above doesn't seem to work. Any idea how it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this in Access 2007:

--The lazy way assuming all KEY_ID values are ####.A

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS T 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON LEFT(T.Key_ID,4) = LEFT(T2.Key_ID,4);
```

--If you want to join everything to the left of the period

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS T 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON Mid(T.Key_ID,1,Instr(1,T.Key_ID,".",1)-1) = Mid(T2.Key_ID,1,Instr(1,T2.Key_ID,".",1)-1);
```

Comment: Thanks .. the Key_ID may contain more than 4 characters to the left of the period, and may contain non-numeric characters as well

Comment: Does the 2nd one help?  The 2nd query will join everything to the left of the period.  What kind of key is it?  I am assuming it is a string field?

Comment: +1 As long as the period is always denoted by a . then the instr example should work great